# Why does "surrogate" inheritance stop working with closures?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, module, closures

For those not familiar, surrogate inheritance looks like the following:

```
var Surrogate = function () {}

var extend = function (Base, Sub) {
  Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
  Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
  Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
}

var Animal = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
  return this.getSound() + ' ' + this.name;
};

Animal.prototype.getSound = function () {
  // Abstract
};

var Cat = function (name) {
  Animal.call(this, name);
};

extend(Animal, Cat);

Cat.prototype.getSound = function () {
  return 'Meow';
};

var kitty = new Cat('Maru');
console.log(kitty.speak()); // Logs "Meow Maru"
console.log(kitty instanceof Animal); // Logs true
console.log(kitty instanceof Cat); // Logs true
console.log(kitty.constructor == Cat); // Logs true
```

Basically to create a constructor function which inherits from `Animal`, we create another constructor function (in this case, `Cat`), call the `Animal` constructor function with the proper value for `this`, and then use the `extend` function to set the `Cat`'s prototype to be an "instance" of `Animal` without a name property. Think of using `extend(Animal, Cat)` being the same as `Cat.prototype = new Animal()` except `Cat.prototype.name` is undefined.

The above works perfectly, and I have a side question about it for later.

I wanted to take that to the next level and hide `Surrogate` inside a closure, so I changed the declarations of `Surrogate` and `extend` to look like this:

```
var extend = (function () {
  var Surrogate = function () {};
  return function (Base, Sub) {
    Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
    Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
  };
});
```

Now when I run the script it fails on the first log statement:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'speak'
```

However, creating another file `extend.js` with the following contents:

```
var Surrogate = function () {};

module.exports = function (Base, Sub) {
  Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
  Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
  Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
}
```

And changing the declaration of `extend` in the main script to `var extend = require('./extend');` works, and `Surrogate` is hidden as expected.

**For the main question:** As far as I know node and other CommonJS systems just wrap modules in a closure function like I was originally attempting to do. Why does the module version work but my version with closures doesn't?

**For the side question mentioned above:** I was surprised by `Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub`. I thought that it should be `Sub.prototype.constructor = Base` but that causes the last logging statement to log `false`. I guess I have already answered the question for myself, but I thought that `constructor` was a property on the constructed object, not the prototype. Is it the other way around?

**UPDATE**

I just tried this with AMD using a module called `extend` defined as follows:

```
define(function () {
  var Surrogate = function () {};

  return function (Base, Sub) {
    Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
    Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
  };
});
```

It works perfectly fine. I feel like I am overlooking something extremely simple here... why does this work fine in module systems but not in plain closures? I have tested all versions (plain, closures, and modules) in node.js, Chrome, and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var extend = (function () {
  var Surrogate = function () {};
  return function (Base, Sub) {
    Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
    Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
  };
});
```

should be

```
var extend = (function () {
  var Surrogate = function () {};
  return function (Base, Sub) {
    Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
    Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
  };
})();
```

(I just appended `()` to it to execute the function.)

or if you want to guard against the possibility that Surrogate might get corrupted(somethign might mess with its constructor function - making it do something):

```
var extend = function (Base, Sub) {
    var Surrogate = function () {};
    Surrogate.prototype = Base.prototype;
    Sub.prototype = new Surrogate();
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
};
```